# Simple merge of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have a relatively simple problem. Two pandas dataframes:

```
    a b
one 1 2
```

and

```
    a c
one 1 3
```

And I want to get

```
    a b c
one 1 2 3
```

I have tried pd.join and pd.concat, which give me duplicate rows or columns, and pd.merge, which merges the data but loses index name.

```
<!-- language: Python -->
a=pd.DataFrame({'a':{'one':1},'c':{'one':3}})
b=pd.DataFrame({'a':{'one':1},'b':{'one':2}})
pd.merge(a,b)

pd.merge(a,b)

   a  c  b
0  1  3  2
```

I acknowledge that I may have missed something trivial about pandas or trying to solve problem in a wrong way.

Comment: Please edit question, because accepted answer have different output as desired `print pd.DataFrame({'a': {'one': 1}, 'c': {'one': 3}, 'b': {'one': 2}})`.

Comment: And your sample data should probably be more than one row.  It is easy to erroneously get the wrong conclusion with such simple data.  For example, what is the expected output for this? `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [2, 1]}, index=['one', 'two'])`

`df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2], 'b': [2, 2, 1]}, index=['one', 'one', 'two'])`

Comment: @jezrael thanks for pointing out the sort order, I accepted Your answer as more complete.

Comment: @Alexander Your point is definitely valid, but really what I wanted was a simple answer to a simple problem and that is what I received, and already accepted the answer. So I think it would not be polite to change the question so that people need to change their answers. However if You feel Your more complex example is relevant, feel free to add it and I happily upvote it.

Comment: I am just pointing out the ambiguity of your join.  Are you joining on the index (in which case you need to deal with potential conflicting values in column `a`), or are you joining on column `a` (in which case you would need to deal with conflicts in the index). Alternatively, you could join on both if you first reset the index on each dataframe. I am logging off, so I don't have an axe to grind.  I just find it ambiguous...

Comment: @Alexander I do not have duplicate index values. I basically agree that there is some ambiguity on the data structuring itself, but this is another problem imo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can add parameters `left_index`, `right_index` and `on` to [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) and then  [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
print pd.merge(a,b, left_index=True, right_index=True, on='a').sort_index(axis=1)
     a  b  c
one  1  2  3
```

Interesting, in `pandas` version `0.18.0` you can specify only one - `left_index` or `right_index`, before in `pandas` version `0.17.2` it was error:

```
print pd.merge(a,b, left_index=True, on='a').sort_index(axis=1)
     a  b  c
one  1  2  3

print pd.merge(a,b, right_index=True, on='a').sort_index(axis=1)
     a  b  c
one  1  2  3
```

Comment: I upvoted you because you took the care of considering the order of columns. Which I don't consider important anyways, as one can reorder whenever it's required.

Comment: a.merge(b, ...) is a little more readable IMO.  +1 none-the-less.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [pd.merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) and specify which index to keep with `left_index` or `right_index`, here is how it works:

```
>>> pd.merge(a,b, on='a', left_index=True)
     a  c  b
one  1  3  2
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try if I can make it work on the more complex data structure.

Comment: @jezrael does it matter ?

Comment: @MedAli - yes, because OP it wants, see 8 line in question.

Comment: Thanks, ordering is not actually important, what was important was the index name.